# How to get position last wrote in a file in JAVA?

Tags: java, file-io, java-io, randomaccessfile

I want to write a circular log file:

```
public class CircularLogFile {
    public static final String LOG_FILE_NAME = "circular.log";
    public static final int LOG_FILE_SIZE_MAX = 256;

    public static void write(String line) throws IOException {
        //BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(logFileName, true));
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(LOG_FILE_NAME, "rw");
        System.out.println("file size: "+raf.length());
        System.out.println("file pointer: "+raf.getFilePointer());
        if (raf.length() >= LOG_FILE_SIZE_MAX && raf.getFilePointer() >= LOG_FILE_SIZE_MAX) {
            raf.seek(0);
        } else if (raf.length() >= LOG_FILE_SIZE_MAX && raf.getFilePointer() < LOG_FILE_SIZE_MAX) {
        } else if (raf.length() < LOG_FILE_SIZE_MAX) {
            raf.seek(raf.length());
        }

        raf.writeChars(line+"\n");

        raf.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int lineNumber = 0;

        while (true) {
            lineNumber++;
            write("This is Line "+lineNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

the output:

```
This is Line 1400
s is Line 2
This is Line 3
This is Line 4
This is Line 5
This is Line 6
This is Line 7
This is Line 8
This is Line 9
```

not

```
This is Line 10
This is Line 11
This is Line 12
This is Line 4
This is Line 5
This is Line 6
This is Line 7
This is Line 8
This is Line 9
```

I want above result, but I found I cannot get the position last wrote in file, how to get?

Comment: it's not very clear.
Seeing your code, the output should begin by `This is Line 1`

Comment: Why is 1400, 2, 3, 4 incorrect but 12, 4, 5, 6 is just fine?

Comment: Even if you get the last write position (from where? magic?), that doesn't help you when you want to change the length of old lines, read, shift subsequent file contents.

Comment: Does this question get where a file pointer is, and store it in the code? Then, when you want to know where the file pointer has moved, it will print the 9 most recent places? Or will it print everything in the list? And I agree with @davidhxxx the first line will be "This is line 1", not 10. And are you overwriting or appending to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to is pretty tricky and in my opinion it might not even be the best way of dealing with it. You are using and abusing File I/O (expensive and with your objective, somewhat hard).

Are you dealing with such large files that you can't use data structures to parse the file and hold the output before flushing it? It would require minimal computation and minimize I/O reads/writes while making it easier to work with